# How to use selected text in apple script? I want to add text before and after it

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Idea: I select text, and it gets replaced with `<sometag>selected text</sometag>`.

Code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "<tag>[what should go here]</tag>"

    return input
end run
```

Comment: _"I select text, and it gets replaced with selected text."_  So, isn't that replacing the text with itself ?  Otherwise, I don't get it.

Comment: I have edited it. Some elements were hidden by stack.

Comment: Thanks.  That's easy, though I don't have a computer currently so you'll need to suffer with an absence of screenshots in my answer, which I'll type out now.

Comment: Thank you, this will literally save hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, have your workflow accept **`Text`** from **`Any Application`** and check the box that is labelled something like **`Output Replaces Selection`**.

Then, all you need is a single **Execute AppleScript** action, in which you should replace any example code with this:

```
on run {input as text}
    return ["<sometag>", input, "</sometag>"] as text
end run
```

which can also be written like this:

```
on run {input as text}
    return "<sometag>" & input & "</sometag>"
end run
```

The workflow would need to be saved as a **Service** or **Quick Action**, and then be activated in *`System Preferences`* where other "Services" are listed.